# For each unique value column of one sheet find the maximum value in matrix in another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

Let's say we have a dataframe as shown below with two variables in Sheet 1.

```
Var1    Var2
1   1
1   2
1   5
1   9
1   10
2   9
2   7
2   2
2   1
2   3
3   4
3   5
3   6
3   8
3   10
```

In sheet 2, we have the following matrix for unique values in Var 2.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  Total
1   115 101 173 230 253 175 111 324 317 251 2050
2   9   24  94  43  58  79  44  82  112 71  616
3   19  21  28  29  68  69  17  42  54  28  375
4   61  53  57  77  132 74  58  125 107 116 860
5   45  37  95  85  99  72  58  176 197 136 1000
6   18  36  34  37  63  48  29  82  107 92  546
7   6   11  40  56  89  53  20  62  47  62  446
8   30  23  38  80  111 70  35  88  153 131 759
9   43  35  62  94  135 122 71  215 230 122 1129
10  14  20  42  46  62  47  37  126 143 105 642
Total   360 361 663 777 1070    809 480 1322    1467    1114
```

Desired output:

For each unique ID in Var 1, what is the value in Var 2 that has the highest sum of row total and column total.

For this dummy example this is the result.

[image]

**Note:** In the solution, I want to use sheet name for the matrix like sheet2 as a user input from a dropdown list. Hence, XLOOKUP function cannot not be used in the formula.

Comment: Can you append the tables as text instead of images? That will make things easier to anyone trying to answer you.

Comment: Without sharing anything from row and column numbers to sheet names to be referenced to, or even an attempted formula referencing any of those, how do you expect a proper answer? I didn't even understand what you ment after seeing the answer provided by Mayukh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula and try to adapt with your data as per your suit:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E15</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _var1, A2:A16,
     _var2, B2:B16,
     _uniqVar2r, XLOOKUP(_var2,E2:E11,P2:P11),
     _uniqVar2c, XLOOKUP(_var2,F1:O1,F12:O12),
     _merged, SORT(HSTACK(_var1,_var2,_uniqVar2r+TOCOL(_uniqVar2c)),{1,3},{1,-1}),
     INDEX(_merged,XMATCH(UNIQUE(_var1),_var1),{1,2,3}))
```

---

To show working when the data is in different sheet as well:

[image]

---

Updated:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E15</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _var1, A2:A16,
     _var2, B2:B16,
     _uniqVar2r, VLOOKUP(_var2,INDIRECT(D1&"!A2:L11"),12,0),
     _uniqVar2c, HLOOKUP(_var2,INDIRECT(D1&"!B1:K12"),12,0),
     _merged, SORT(HSTACK(_var1,_var2,_uniqVar2r+TOCOL(_uniqVar2c)),{1,3},{1,-1}),
     INDEX(_merged,XMATCH(UNIQUE(_var1),_var1),{1,2,3}))
```

---

File for download: **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckCZQEFnNXW5BjZTt?e=pIQbUa)**

Comment: That's brilliant. I didn't even understand the question!

Comment: I am not getting the same answer when the matrix is in another sheet as given in the question. I am using indirect function to read the matrix

Comment: Can we achieve the same result using lambda() function instead of xlookup?

Comment: because XLOOKUP doesn't have a built-in capability to reference different sheets dynamically based on a dropdown list or cell value. so its not a great function to use;however, lamba does. In future, I might want to use the sheetname as a dropdown list. Can you post a solution that uses a function other than xlookup

Comment: @vp_050 using `LAMBDA()` i had no interest to share because it makes more complicated. However here it is `=LET(
         _var1, A2:A16,
         _var2, B2:B16,
         _data, WRAPROWS(DROP(REDUCE("",INDIRECT(D1&"!A1:L12"),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,y))),1),12),
         _sorted, SORT(HSTACK(_var1,_var2,VLOOKUP(_var2,_data,12,0)+TOCOL(HLOOKUP(_var2,_data,12,0))),{1,3},{1,-1}),
         INDEX(_sorted,XMATCH(UNIQUE(_var1),_var1),{1,2,3}))`